How to sample uniformly from the unit sphere in the subspace orthogonal to $\mathbf{1}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$?
Given the vector $\mathbf{1} = (1, 1, \ldots, 1)^T \in \mathbb{R}^n$, the unit sphere in the subspace orthogonal to $\mathbf{1}$ is defined as $\{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n : \mathbf{1}^T \mathbf{x} = 0 \text{ and }\|\mathbf{x}\|_2 = 1\}$. How can a point be sampled uniformly from this space?


Sample a vector from the n-dimensional standard normal distribution. 2. Normalize that vector (if it is zero, pick again until it isn't). Then it is on the sphere, and is uniformly distributed. 3. Check on which side of your plane the point is. If on the wrong side, throw it away and restart from 1.


Alternatively for step 3, negate the vector if it is on the wrong side; probably better.

@kaba, how do you know that it's uniformly distributed on the sphere?

It is because the standard normal distribution is spherically symmetric. I realize I read your problem statement incorrectly. What I describe above provides a uniform sampling of a half-sphere, with 1 as the normal of the plane which cuts the sphere in half.

@kaba I think you could do your 1 and 2 in $n-1$ dimensions and then transform these samples from $\mathbb R^{n-1}$ to the subspace in question

The subspace you define is an intersection of an (origin-passing) plane and an n-sphere (at origin). That intersection is an (n - 1)-sphere, which you can sample as described above, and then transform that.

Right, you got it :)

You can reduce this problem to sampling from the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. To see this, choose any rotation matrix $R$ that maps $(1, \ldots, 1)^T$ to a multiple of $(0, \ldots, 0, 1)^T$. Then a vector $\mathbf{x}$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{1}$ if and only if $R\mathbf{x}$ is orthogonal to $(0, \ldots, 0, 1)^T$. Since $R$ also preserves lengths we find that
$$
    \left\{ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n \ | \ \mathbf{1}^T \mathbf{x} = 0 \text{ and } \|\mathbf{x}\|_2 = 1 \right\} = 
    \left\{
        R^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}
            \mathbf{y} \\
            0
        \end{pmatrix}
         \ | \ \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \text{ and }\|\mathbf{y}\|_2 = 1 \right\} \, .
$$
To sample uniformly from your set you can thus sample $\mathbf{y}$ uniformly from the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ and then set $\mathbf{x} = R^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{y} \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Can you please detail a bit more you your answer? I am not sure I understand what you mean.

I have made my answer a bit more explicit. Please let me know if anything is still unclear.

Just a (possibly trivial) question @user1363745: I get some intuition, but how could one show - in the equality between sets - that the left hand side is contained in the right hand side?

Let $\mathbf{x}$ be an element from the left hand side. To show that it is contained in the right hand side we need to show that $R\mathbf{x}$ has length 1 and is orthogonal to $(0,\ldots,0,1)^T$. Since $R$ is a rotation we have $|R\mathbf{x}|_2 = |\mathbf{x}|_2 = 1$ and since $R$ maps $\mathbf{1} = (1, \ldots, 1)^T$ to a multiple of $\mathbf{e}_n = (0, \ldots, 0, 1)^T$ we have $\mathbf{e}_n^T R\mathbf{x} = (R^T\mathbf{e}_n)^T \mathbf{x} = (R^{-1}\mathbf{e}_n)^T \mathbf{x} \sim \mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{x} = 0$.

That is clear, but how does it show that if $x$ belongs to the lhs then there exists a lower dimensional $y$ with unit norm such that $x=R^{-1}(y,0)$? Am I missing some elementary fact? @user1363745

$R \mathbf{x}$ is orthogonal to $(0, \ldots, 0, 1)$ if and only if $R \mathbf{x}$ has the form $(\mathbf{y},0)$. And the norm of $(\mathbf{y},0)$ is just the norm of $\mathbf{y}$.
